# combined properties in expression angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller with contact object in his scope.

If the contact has first name or last name, I want to show `first-name`<space>`last-name`.

My problem is that when the contact has no first name or last name. In this situation I want to show the user `Create new contact` but because there is a space between the first name and last name in the expression, it displays only the spacing.

Start typing in the inputs and you will that, basically, both of divs should show the same.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  //$scope.contact = {
  //  FirstName: 'first',
  //  LastName: 'last'
  //}
  
  $scope.contact = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.FirstName" placeholder="first name" />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.LastName" placeholder="last name" />
  <hr />
  <!-- If I add space between first and last name it will never show 'Create new conttact' -->
  {{contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName || 'Create new contact'}}<br />
  {{contact.FirstName + contact.LastName || 'Create new contact'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if to fix your issue.
I have updated the code to match your requirements. Hope this helps.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  //$scope.contact = {
  //  FirstName: 'first',
  //  LastName: 'last'
  //}
  
  $scope.contact = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.FirstName" placeholder="first name" />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.LastName" placeholder="last name" />
  <hr />
  <!-- If I add space between first and last name it will never show 'Create new conttact' -->
  {{contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName}}
<span ng-if="(contact.FirstName == null || contact.FirstName == '') && (contact.LastName == null || contact.LastName == '')">Create New Contact</span>

</div>
```

There can be many ways this can be achieved. But since you want to achieve this in expressions only it can be done as below.. Just use the trim() in the expression.

**Second solution:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.FirstName" placeholder="first name" />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact.LastName" placeholder="last name" />
  <hr />
  <!-- If I add space between first and last name it will never show 'Create new conttact' -->
  {{(contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName).trim() || 'Create New Contact'}}

</div>
```

Comment: I already knew these solutions, I think there's a way to solve it by using expressions only.

Comment: Added a second solution to achieve the result using expressions only. Please note there may be different ways to achieve one thing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can just use `ng-show`/`ng-hide`:

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
    <span ng-show="contact.FirstName && contact.LastName">
        {{contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName}}
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="contact.FirstName && contact.LastName">
        Create new contact
    </span>
</div>
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: they actually want `||` not `&&` in this case, but other than that, this is the correct approach.  Although, using `||`, they are going to get an empty space at the beginning of the string if they only have a `LastName`, probably still not optimal to do it this way; should have a property on the model that does the concat.

Comment: I already knew these solutions, I think there's a way to solve it by using expressions only.

Answer (score 1):

You here have 2 options 1 create a function that return true or false if you have first or last name or do the verification into html:

**Solution 1:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {  
  $scope.contact = {};
  $scope.verifyContacts =  function(){
     return contact.FirstName || contact.LastName;
 }
});

<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ctrl">    
  <span ng-hide="verifyContacts()">Create new contact</span>
  <span ng-show="verifyContacts()">{{contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName}}</span>
</div>
```

**Soution 2:**

This soution will invole to write the expresion form the verifyContacts function from above solution inline  so your html will look like:

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
 <span ng-hide="contact.FirstName || contact.LastName">Create new contact</span>
  <span ng-show="contact.FirstName || contact.LastName">{{contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName}}</span>
</div>
```

I personally prefer the first solution.

Edit: presenting the third solution:P

**Solution 3:**
You can add a space at the end of the first name if the first name is available so you don't need to concat the strings with space

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    controller('ctrl', function($scope) {  
      $scope.contact = {};
      contact.FirstName = contact.FirstName ?  contact.FirstName + ' ' : contact.FirstName;
     }
    });

<div> {{contact.FirstName + contact.LastName || 'Create new contact'}} </div>
```

this will work but as you can see in your code that the input fields are not displayed so you most probably will need a back-end function for that or something.

Comment: I already knew these solutions, I think there's a way to solve it by using expressions only.

Comment: @MoshFeu please see the third solution this should do the trick :P